# Blocking in gunicorn server when open up an idle connection but not in uWSGI

Tags: python, uwsgi, gunicorn

A simple snippet to show my test:

```
import flask

app = flask.Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def index():
    return 'Hello, world!'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Save it to `server.py`, then start it with two ways apart:

1. gunicorn -b 127.0.0.1:8000 server:app
2. uwsgi --http :8000 --module server --callable app

So, each of them will listens at 8000 port on localhost when they invoked seperately.

What makes me confused is, I create an idle connection with `telnet` then, just invoke `telnet 127.0.0.1 8000` in another terminal workspace, and then I visit server with command `curl http://127.0.0.1:8000`:

1. The process of curl will block with gunicorn server
2. But in uwsgi way, `curl` gets response immediately and the idle connection with `telnet` was still alive!

Why is uwsgi non-blocking here? It's only one worker in my understanding. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

uWSGI uses deferred accept (it is a feature of some OSes), so until there is no data in the socket the process will not be wake-up for accept()

Comment: Thank you very much! Does gunicorn have this option? I preferred to use gunicorn in general working.